# How to use result of Java FuzzyScore?

Tags: fuzzy-search

I need to correlate data from two sources based on first names, which might be slightly different after a Customer Service Rep has (attempted) to fix typos.

At first I thought "FuzzyScore" might help, until I realized I have no idea how to use it properly. Looking at https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/similarity/FuzzyScore.html and my basic conclusion: it returns a near random number

Just look at their examples:

```
 score.fuzzyScore("Workshop", "w")                     = 1
 score.fuzzyScore("Workshop", "ws")                    = 2
 score.fuzzyScore("Workshop", "wo")                    = 4      // excuse me???
 score.fuzzyScore("Apache Software Foundation", "asf") = 3
```

What test can I use to say a match is found?

Comment: score = fuzzy.fuzzyScore("ajbhdikdidik", "abhdikdidi"); // 26! seriously, how is this useful?

Comment: I switched to FuzzySearch, it returns a number 0 - 100, where 100 is an exact match.

Comment: FuzzyScore works fine, but check the meaning of the arguments: https://itsallbinary.com/similar-strings-or-same-sounding-strings-algorithms-comparison-apache-implementation-in-java/ (the first is term and the second is query)